# Automorphism of a group which stabilizes a series

Tags: group-theory

I need help with the notion of "automorphism of a group which stabilizes a series", I don't know what it means. Can you help me with this sentence?

$C/C_C(K)$ is isomorphic with a group of automorphisms of $K$ which $\textbf{stabilizes the series}$ $K\geq T\geq 1$

I just would like to know what is the relation between these automorphisms and the series. Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the definition you are looking for (see for example Suzuki, *Group Theory II* (pg. 20) or [this article](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1255448649) by P. Hall). Let

$$G = G_0 \geq G_1 \geq G_2 \geq \ldots \geq G_n = 1$$

be a series of subgroups of $G$. We say that an automorphism $\sigma \in \operatorname{Aut}(G)$ stabilizes the above series, if for all $i$ and $g \in G_{i-1}$, we have

$$(G_ig)^\sigma = G_ig$$

Comment: I think too, thank you very much!!

Comment: The other definition is that for every $\sigma$ and $i$, $\sigma(G_i) = G_i$. This other definition is much, much weaker. Mikko's definition is more common, and should basically say your $C/C_C(K)$ group is nilpotent. The other definition says almost nothing about $C/C_C(K)$, but it does say something about that way $C$ acts on $G$, so is occasionally used.